# PHP Multicurl high cpu usage

Tags: php, curl

Running this code on my 1 vCPU VPS with 70 url and the cpu is jumping to 100%, is it normal?

**VPS - (LAMP) - PHP Version 7.0.25, Intel Xeon CPU E5-2650 @ 2.00GHz**

```
$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++)
{
    $random = rand(1,9999);

    $link = trim($urls[$i]);

    $link = $link."?".$random;

    $url = trim($link);
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );

    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}
do 
{
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} 
while($running > 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes because that's exactly what you're asking for when you're not using `curl_multi_select()` to wait for activity before you call `curl_multi_exec()` again...

This simple change should work a whole lot better:

```
do {
   curl_multi_select($master);
   curl_multi_exec($master, $running);
} while ($running);
```

Comment: this should definitely help, but even with curl_multi_select, it will still use an exorbitant amount of cpu, at least that has been my experience over the years. something bad about php's wrapper for the underlying call, i assume.